# what's the difference between printf a floating-point variable and constant?

Tags: c, floating-point

Here's my code:

```
float x = 21.195;
printf("%.2f\n", x);
printf("%.2f\n", 21.195);
```

I would expect both print statements to have identical output, but instead, the first prints `21.19`, and the second prints `21.20`.

Could someone explain why the output is different?

Comment: Note:, that depending  on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` and other factors, the outputs could be the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The values are different.  The first is a `float`, which is typically 4 bytes.  The second is a `double`, which is typically 8 bytes.

The rules for rounding are based on the third digit after the decimal place.  So, in one case, the value is something like 21.19499997 and the other 21.1950000000001, or something like that.  (These are made  up to illustrate the issue with rounding and imprecise numeric formats.)

Comment: Sorry Gordon, didn't saw you answer when I typed

Comment: Floating point numbers prove the existence of (your favorite deity/ies here) by negation because they are clearly the work of (your favorite personification of evil here). :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help~( ^_^ )

Comment: Actual values are [`21.19499969482421875` in 32-bit](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=050049046049057053) and [`21.195000000000000284217094304` in 64-bit](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=050049046049057053).

Answer (score 7):

By default 21.195 is a double.

If you want a float, write :

`21.195F`

or

`(float)21.195`

Regards

Comment: appreciate your help too~#^_^#

Answer (score 0):

When a floating point variable is defined in C, by *default* it is set to *double*. So x is *set to float* because you mentioned it *explicitly*, else 21.195 is considered to be double.

Now, as mentioned above, *float* is usually about *4 bytes* and *double* is about *8 bytes*. So a *float* value has *24 significant bits with 7 digits of precision* and *double* has *53 significant bits with 15 to 16 digits of precision*.

A roundoff function %.2f works to round off the number correct to 2 decimal places and *checks the third digit after the decimal point* for rounding off. 
So 21.195 in float expands to 21.19499998 and is then reduced to 21.19 after %.2f an 21.195 in double expands to 21.1950000000000001 and hence reduces to 21.20.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There's no "default" - float variables are declared `float` and double variables are declared `double`.  You seem to be talking about `21.195` which is a *literal*, not a variable.  The rules about literals are that if it contains `.` and no suffix it is a `double`;  if it has a `f` suffix it's a `float`.

Comment: @M.M : Yes I meant the same. 21.195 when declared as x is a variable and 21.195 itself is a literal. Missed that point in the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.